# Parse ISODate to object after aggregate

Tags: mongodb, rust

I am trying to query a MongoDB database with Rust. My code is as follows:

```
    let mut data = Vec::<ManagementReportResult>::new();
    let level_docs = doc!{
        "$unwind": "$managements"
    };
    let project_result = doc!{
      "$project": {
        "client": "$clientCode",
        "product": "$productCode",
        "case": 1,
        "action": "$managements.action",
        "createdAt": 1
      }
    };

    let pipeline = vec![level_docs, project_result];
    let mut cursor = self.collection.aggregate(pipeline, None).await?;

    while let Some(management) = cursor.next().await {
      let item: ManagementReportResult = from_document(management?)?;
      data.push(item);
    }
```

The parsing struct looks like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all="camelCase")]
pub struct ManagementReportResult {
  pub client: String,
  ...
  #[serde(with = "chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime")]
  pub created_at: DateTime<Utc>
}
```

but on this line:
`let item: ManagementReportResult = from_document(management?)?;`
I get the error:
*error: DeserializationError {
message: "invalid type: map, expected a formatted date and time string or a unix timestamp",
}*

If I print the document this is what is has in the date field:
"createdAt": DateTime(
2021-11-23T05:17:14.892Z,
),

Any held would be much appreciated